# How to convert Query in Body-> Raw to query String in url

Tags: get

How do I convert this query to query String in url?
The goal is to apply the filter passed as a query in Postman request and convert it to url, so the query is in the url and not separate of it.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "gte": "2019-08-12T06:00:00",
                            "lt": "2019-08-12T07:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialise your JSON into a URL-encoded string, and then pass that encoded string as one big query parameter. This parameter could then be decoded back to JSON in your backend.

Using something like [this](https://www.urlencoder.io) might help.

Comment: Thanks it really helped !